# ConvertAll fails with NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I am trying to flatten a multi-dimensional array with ConvertAll but I can't get it to work:

```
 Private Function Flatten(ByRef a As Object) As Object
    Dim elements As Integer = 0
    Dim size As Integer
    For r = 0 To a.Rank - 1
        size = a.GetUpperBound(r) - a.GetLowerBound(r) + 1
        If elements = 0 Then
            elements = size
        Else
            elements = elements * size
        End If
    Next
    Dim result(elements - 1) As Object
    ' Fails !
    result = a.ConvertAll(a, New Converter(Of Object, Object)(Function(x) x))
    Return result
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim a(,) As Integer = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
    Dim b(5) As Integer
    b = Flatten(a)
End Sub
```

Why does it throw NullReferenceException?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the msdn [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx), `Array.ConvertAll()` takes zero based one-dimensional array for `TInput`. You have `a(,)` defined as 2 dimensional

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, you're right. I was mislead by this "When copying between multidimensional arrays, the array behaves like a long one-dimensional array, where the rows (or columns) are conceptually laid end to end. For example, if an array has three rows (or columns) with four elements each, copying six elements from the beginning of the array would copy all four elements of the first row (or column) and the first two elements of the second row (or column)." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx, which lead to me to think I could get away with it.